# How to include spatial location (x,y) in GAM predict?

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster, gam

I've developed my generalised additive model using the `mgcv` pakcage in R. A simpler version of my gam model is

*data: 
[mydata](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11rS7O3rlYTbwv9i4hF3XLetzIlfyfcW0)
[raster file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QrPxcawu5tbmYVLsQtnKlQ6HjC0CrYOq)*

```
library(readxl)
library(mgcv)
mydata <- read_excel("C:/Desktop/mydata.xlsx")
mygam <- gam(conc ~ s(var1)+ s(var2) + s(var3) + s(X,Y), data = mydata)
```

`var1`, `var2` and `var3` are land use variables; `(X,Y)` are point locations of each sampled data `conc`. My aim now is to create a predicted surface from this model, using `predict.gam`. I have all my variables in individual raster files. Thanks to one of the answers in [this post](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_run_a_GAM_model_in_GIS) I can predict using

```
mygam2 <- gam(conc ~ s(var1)+ s(var2) + s(var3), data = mydata)    

library(raster)
rs_stack(var1,var2,var3)
predict(rs_stack,mygam2,filename="file_name.tif")
```

(the prediction may take a few minutes)

But this does not include the spatial location`(X,Y)`, as they are in point format, therefore can't be transformed to a raster layer as the land use variables. **My question is how can I account for `(X,Y)` in the prediction, with the rest of the raster layers?**

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think a potential workaround is to extract all values of variables from point locations, export them as tables, and then do the prediction as `data.frame`. but I have a very very large area, with 25m resolution, so working with raster would be a much better option (if it's achievable...)

Comment: You could create a raster layer containing the x coordinates and another containing the y coordinates.

Comment: A MCVE would help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Florian I've edited my question with data provided.

Comment: @Florian If I inlcude X,Y as separate raster files, won't they be accounted as 'values' instead of sptial location?